# Preg_match_all regex expression is not fully correct

Tags: php, arrays, regex

I was using Preg_match_all in php and written a regex which was working fine as expected 
Regex : `'/"([0-9A-z ]*)("|$)/'`
String to be searched are :

```
["100"]
["100","200"]
["100","200","300"]
```

Array from preg

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => '"100"',
    1 => '"200"',
    2 => '"300"',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => '100',
    1 => '200',
    2 => '300',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => '"',
    1 => '"',
    2 => '"',
  ),
)
```

So i was getting data from array 1

But now we are also getting data like :

```
[100]
[100,200]
```

and i want a single regex for both the types but unable to do so.
i tried to write

```
/"([0-9A-z ]*)("|$)|[0-9]*/
```

But it was not giving what i expected.
Can anyone help me with this

One more thing is needed :- 
When i was using regex Lets says the data is like :-

```
["",""]
```

Array i was getting :-

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => '""',
    1 => '""',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => '',
    1 => '',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => '"',
    1 => '"',
  ),
)
```

So from this i was taking array 1 , so getting empty 
But all the regex i am getting is giving me :-

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
  ),
)
```

Can a regex be like which gives me the with all the following conditions.

Comment: Why do you have `A-z`? Are you planning to also match "[ ] \ ^ _ \`"? Another question: is your data pre-filtered? Is there need to check if there are values inside `[...]`?

Comment: I think i should remove it. as only numbers would be there in data. Its not prefiltered , data can be like this [""] or []

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? There may be a better way of doing it than regex.

Comment: Instead you can simply use `in_array` function of php instead of regex

Comment: I think json_decode do all the things i needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## A non-regex way

You can leverage [`eval` method](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php):

```
$string = '["100","200","300"]';
// $string = '[100,200, 300]';
eval('$array = array('.$string.');');
print_r($array);
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/O8Ml3U)

## Regex way

There can be 2 approaches depending on your input.

The hardest way is to make sure we are inside `[...]`:

```
(?:\[|(?<!^)\G)"?,?([0-9 ]+)"?,?(?=[^]]*\])
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/gM6wG7/2)

A more efficient regex can be used if your input is already pre-filtered and you only get strings as you have shown above:

```
[0-9 ]+(?="?|,)
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/gM6wG7/4)

Comment: hi i tried it but the thing is that one case is still pending when we dont have comma in between ["100""200"] what should i do in that case

Comment: If you use `[0-9 ]+(?="?|,)` you will get this case covered. If you decided on an eval method, you can preprocess the input by, saying, [replacing "" with a ",".](https://ideone.com/Knbb3y)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in the case the simple expression helps you

```
/([\d]+)/g
```

[DEMO](https://www.regex101.com/r/zV6eY5/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply decode it the way you want with an in build function PHP provides.

Use `json_decode`

You can see the implementation here :-
https://ideone.com/IFEe6p

This function will work for everything except   `[]   [,,]` 
These type of strings should be handled separately.